# Orchard how to modify which Zones are available under Widgets

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I am very new in Orchard, and little bit confused on how to customise zones.

When I go to Widgets menu in Orchard Admin - using the 'TheThemeMachine' theme I can see list of Zones available there.

Now, when I create a new theme, following this tutorial: "http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Writing-a-new-theme" - then go to Widgets, I got following warning:

"Widgets in these zones will not appear anywhere when your currently active theme is applied. They might still appear in selectively applied (e.g. mobile) themes."

I understand that warning, my questions are:
1. How do I remove zones that I don't use? Or do I have to remove the 'TheThemeMachine' theme to also remove the zones?
2. After I created the new theme 'MyFirstTheme', I cannot see any zones listed under Widgets. Do we need to do something else to enable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not to remove zones, the problem is that these zones don't exist, but you still have widgets in them. All you have to do is move those widgets to zones that actually exist, or re-create these zones in your theme. Seems like you forgot to list your zones in the theme.txt manifest file.